# How to change ip address from VM with Azure-CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ip

Im having some difficult to change the public ip address dynamic from my VM using Azure-cli, I need to change the ip everytime when I restart the machine, Im using Ubuntu and shellscript.

I've created the public ip

`az network public-ip create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyIp`

to create/update the NIC

`az network nic ip-config create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyIpConfig --nic-name MyNic --make-primary`

create the nic

`az network nic create -g MyResourceGroup --vnet-name MyVnet --subnet MySubnet -n MyNic`

Comment: It's not clear what you want, please provide more details about your requirements and the example expected.

Comment: I need to change the ip everytime when the machine comes up, Im using the above commands but It`s not working

Comment: Why do you want to change the IP every time when starting the VM? the public IP or the private IP?

Comment: Agreed. I would be curious to see why you would like to change the private *and/or* public ips every time when starting the VM.

Comment: Resolved guys, i just has created a new public ip address and updated my nic, Im doing some work around and need that =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the procedure to assign a public ip to a network interface attached to a virtual machine:

1. Create public ip

   `az network public-ip create --name myVMPublicIP --resource-group myResourceGroup`
2. Assign public ip to an ip configuration of a network interface attached to a virtual machine

   `az network nic ip-config update \
     --name ipconfigmyVM \
     --nic-name myVMVMNic \
     --resource-group myResourceGroup \
     --public-ip-address myVMPublicIP`

See documentation: [Associate a public IP address to a virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/associate-public-ip-address-vm)